# Bluebird promise concurrency in mongo db collection migrate operations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, bluebird

I am working on a script where I need to take the data from a mongodb collection, process it with some renames and mapping and put the data to other collection. I am using this script in expressjs with mongodb-native client for nodejs.

Here is my script with all the running functions

```
const syncCustomerWithCustomerv1 = function(params){
    utils.connectDB().then((client) => {
        Promise.map(aggregateDocumentsv1(client, params), function(cursor){
            Promise.map(getCustomerDatav1(cursor), function(customer){

                var hashedMap = makeHashedObjectv1(customer);
                makeDatav1(client, customer, hashedMap).then((response)=> {
                    console.log("success");
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    reject(error);
                })
            }, {concurrency: 500});
        }, {concurrency: 500}).then((reponse) => {  
            console.log("data inserted");
        })
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Now in function named syncCustomerWithCustomerv1, I am able to fetch the data from old collection to the new collection, but I do not think any concurrent requests are taken into this. while the above operation is running, I am not able to hit api, so when the operation is running it does not allow other requests to run along.

- In the Promise.map(aggregateDocumentsv1), I am taking the list of cursors. each element in listOfCursor array has a cursor which when queried yields 500 records.
- I am expecting it gets each cursor and assigns it to the next Promise.map(getCustomerDatav1(cursor)), Now this yields each customer I have in my previous mongo collection, and we can perform the mapping operations on the object we got and then insert the data into the new collection.

If anyone gets the issue and know how I can make it better concurrent so that I can run this script and also my APIs also don't get any downtime.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?? the concurrency in bluebird sets a limit on the operations that are executed concurrently, i.e. in any slice of time there are at most 500 instances of the resolver function are running. if you do not specify this option, the function will be called on all of your documents concurrently.

Comment: I think you have this the wrong way around. `Promise.map(arrayOfItems, e => functionReturningPromise(e))` is basically a "helper" for `Promise.all(arrayOfItems.map(e => functionReturningPromise(e))`. You are providing both with an "array of promises" and attempting to "iterate" the results, but that's not what the function argument of `Promise.map()` does.

Comment: Hey @ilLunn NeilLunn, So there should be second Promise.map that needs to rewritten as Promise.any.

Comment: If you look at my usage example the **first** argument is basically an array, and the **second** is the function which is basically `Array.prototype.map()`. Most importantly, this is meant to **return an array of data**, and you're ignoring that return. You would be advised to rather explain what you are trying to do, since the code is a bit messy and you are actually wrapping methods that already return a Promise with a new Promise. Try and walk through the logic of what is supposed to be happening in dot points in your question.

Comment: Hey @NeilLunn, I have updated some dot points explaining what I have expected from the promises. Let me know your views.

Comment: Umm. Can I try a simplified explanation here. It appears to be that you a actually 1. Reading customer name and email from one collection. 2. Doing a "find or create" to write the same name and email data to another collection. Question is "Is this in the same database server, or on different machines? And is the target collection ( the "find or create" one ) actually pre-exisitng with data in it, OR can it just be completely overwritten". That's my basic interpretation and actually what I wanted you to explain. No offence, but there's little point trying to explain current code.

Comment: this operation would be performed on same database server on the same machine, and target collection is not existing, so for the first time it would get populated with the new fields and the second time the cron would run weekly checking if the users existing or not, if exists then it would just update otherwise it would create the newly created users also.

Comment: @ChitrankDixit can you specifically pinpoint where do you need help. It would be great if you could place only relevant part of your code in the question rather than entire script. can you narrow down your problem?

Comment: What is `reject(error);` calling?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about MongoDB, but there are a few problems with your promise code:

- For any function (be it `Promise.map` or `then`) to be able to wait for the result of an asynchronous callback, that callback must `return` a promise to be awaited
- You are doing 500 concurrent operations, where each of those operations does 500 concurrent operations. That's a total concurrency factor of 250000! You probably want to reduce that a bit.

```
function syncCustomerWithCustomerv1(params){
    utils.connectDB().then(client => {
        return Promise.map(aggregateDocumentsv1(client, params), cursor => {
//      ^^^^^^
            return Promise.map(getCustomerDatav1(cursor), customer => {
//          ^^^^^^
                var hashedMap = makeHashedObjectv1(customer);
                return makeDatav1(client, customer, hashedMap).then(response => {
//              ^^^^^^
                    console.log("success");
                }, error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }, {concurrency: 500});
        }, {concurrency: 500})
    }).then(reponse => {  
        console.log("data inserted");
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```